PrimeVue + Laravel Intertia SSR - Cannot use import statement outside a module
PrimeVue - 3.48.1
Laravel - 11
Inertia - 1.1.0
When starting ssr mode, I get the error below
php artisan inertia:start-ssr
(node:9349) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/Laravel/test/node_modules/primevue/config/config.esm.js:1
import { FilterMatchMode } from 'primevue/api';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1290:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1342:27)

Node.js v21.6.2

My file configuration vite.config.js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['primevue']
    }
});

run command php artisan inertia:start-ssr

https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/5166
